# Setting Font Size for "HTML Email using Python" with respect to "Outlook's Font - Size"

Tags: python, email, python-2.7, outlook, html-email

I am using below lines of code for setting up font size in **HTML EMAIL using Python**:

> ```
>     <html>
>     <head>
>       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
>       <title>html title</title>
>       <style type="text/css" media="screen">
>         table{
>             empty-cells:hide;
>         }
>
>       </style>
>     </head>
>     <body> <font face="Calibri" size="3" color = "black">
> ```

Same gets reflected in Outlook mail as font size = "12".

On setting

> ```
>     <font face="Calibri" size="2" color = "black">
> ```

Same gets reflected in Outlook mail as font size = "10".

**I need to set Outlook mail fonts exactly to "11". Kindly suggest for the same. With "2.5" also it takes Outlook font size as "10".**

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<p style="width:20px;height:20px;">This is an automated E-mail<br>
</p>
```

this helps you to set/adjust the size of font in html tags

Answer (score -1):

Outlook uses Word as an email editor (i.e. to render your HTML markup). That's why you see a difference.

You can read more about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201%28v=office.12%29.aspx)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: All those docs say is that `size` is supported, and nothing at all about Outlook's rendering engine's differences.

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend using `style="font-size:22px;"` in your font tag (or whatever the px value is of your browser's `size="11"`. `size` is very loosely interpreted between clients/browsers anyway, whereas `px` isn't.

I currently only use `size` as a fallback font-size for Windows Phone 7+ because their IEMobile engine doesn't get my font-size CSS anywhere else (tried `span`, `td`, `font`).